# EasyPHP won't start - error 0xc000007b even though C++ redistributables are there

Tags: easyphp

EasyPHP-devserver-17.0 throws this error when starting the dashboard (win 7 x64):

[image]

Problem is I installed the 3 C++ redistributables they list: http://www.easyphp.org/faq_devserver.php#collapse001

[image]

- first x64
- then x64 + x86
- then removed everything, installed only x86
- then added x64 back

Still get the same error.

How can I fix it or get more info about what exactly is failing?

Comment: Try to install vc15 (https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/VC_redist.x64.exe or https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/VC_redist.x86.exe)

Comment: Thanks @PeterEstiven, but I ended up installing XAMPP. I have no idea why I kept using that pathetic kit. I eventually got EasyPHP WebServer running, but it would only listen on my LAN IP, not localhost. Even if I'd change the Listen and ServerName fields in httpd.conf, an EasyPHP .exe would go and change them right back to the network ones when starting up. XAMPP FTW.